# Sorting an array based on special character set in php

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

I have this very problem:
Consider an array of n words with lower cases. Implement a function to find all words that have the same unique character set. All words with the same set of characters are printed together in a line in the order they appear in the array.

If the inputs are:
6
student
students
dog
studentssess 
god
cat

The expected output should be:
student,students,studentssess,
dog,god,
cat,

I was able to come up with a solution in python, but I need the solution transformed to PHP, your suggestions will help me so much.

The solution in python is this:

```
# Function to group all strings with same characters 
from collections import Counter 

def groupStrings(input): 
    # traverse all strings one by one 
    # dict is an empty dictionary 
    dict={} 

    for word in input: 
        # sort the current string and take it's 
        # sorted value as key 
        # sorted return list of sorted characters 
        # we need to join them to get key as string 
        # Counter() method returns dictionary with frequency of 
        # each character as value 
        wordDict=Counter(word) 

        # now get list of keys 
        key = wordDict.keys() 

        # now sort these keys 
        key = sorted(key) 

        # join these characters to produce key string 
        key = ''.join(key) 

        # now check if this key already exist in 
        # dictionary or not 
        # if exist then simply append current word 
        # in mapped list on key 
        # otherwise first assign empty list to key and 
        # then append current word in it 
        if key in dict.keys(): 
            dict[key].append(word) 
        else: 
            dict[key]=[] 
            dict[key].append(word) 

        # now traverse complete dictionary and print 
        # list of mapped strings in each key seprated by , 
    for (key,value) in dict.iteritems(): 
        print ','.join(dict[key]) 

# Driver program 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    input=['may','student','students','dog','studentssess','god','cat','act','tab','bat','flow','wolf','lambs','amy','yam','balms','looped','poodle'] 
    groupStrings(input)
```

Comment: Please post what you have attempted for PHP.

Comment: do you want someone to convert you python solution to php?

Comment: Yes. that id exactly what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PHP can do everything except `collections.Counter` identically with a different function name or syntax. First you would need to use [`count_chars($word, 1)`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php) as a substitute for `collections.Counter`, followed by mapping the returned array to the character using `chr`.

Afterwards its just replacing the Python syntax with the PHP equivalent.

### Example: https://3v4l.org/V6HBg

```
function groupStrings($input)
{
    $words = $dict = [];
    foreach ($input as $word) {
       //emulate python collections.Counter() using count_chars()
       $wordDict = \count_chars($word, 1);

       //get the character value returned from keys of count_chars()
       $key = \array_map(function($v) {
           return \chr($v);
       }, \array_keys($wordDict));

       //sort alphabetically A-Z (ignores case)
       \natcasesort($key);

       //create an associative index from the key
       $key = \implode('', $key);

       if (!\array_key_exists($key, $dict)) {
           $dict[$key] = [];
       }
       $dict[$key][] = $word;
    }

    foreach ($dict as $key => $word) {
        $words[] = \implode(',', $word);
    }

    return \implode(',', $words);
}

$input = ['student', 'students', 'dog', 'studentssess', 'god', 'cat'];
echo groupStrings($input);
```

**Result:**

```
student,students,studentssess,dog,god,cat
```

**Full Result:**

```
may,amy,yam,student,students,studentssess,dog,god,cat,act,tab,bat,flow,wolf,lambs,balms,looped,poodle
```

---

### Simplified version https://3v4l.org/SuAI5

Since you're only interested in the characters in each word and not the frequency of them, we can replace the costly `count_chars` and `array_map` conversion of the keys to characters, and use `array_unique` on `str_split` instead.

```
function groupStrings($input)
{
    $dict = \array_reduce($input, function(array $out, $in) {
       //retrieve the unique characters of each word
       $key = \array_unique(\str_split($in));

       //sort alphabetically A-Z (ignores case)
       \natcasesort($key);

       //create an associative index from the key
       $key = \implode('', $key);

       if(!\array_key_exists($key, $out)) {
           $out[$key] = [];
       }
       $out[$key][] = $in;

       return $out;
    }, []);

    return \implode(',', \array_map(function($word) {
        return \implode(',', $word);
    }, $dict));
}

$input = ['student', 'students', 'dog', 'studentssess', 'god', 'cat'];
echo groupStrings($input);
```